# Using NSArray and NSDictionary to access a JSON object without a root element

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

Here's an example of my data:

```
[
 {
  code: "DRK",
  exchange: "BTC",
  last_price: "0.01790000",
  yesterday_price: "0.01625007",
  top_bid: "0.01790000",
  top_ask: "0.01833999"
 }
]
```

I'm trying to retrieve the value for last_price  by loading the contents of my NSDictionary into an Array.

```
NSURL *darkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/stats/DRK/BTC"];
NSData *darkData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:darkURL];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *darkDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:darkData options:0 error:&error];

self.darkPosts = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray *darkPostArray = [darkDict objectForKey:@""];

for (NSDictionary *darkDict in darkPostArray) {...
```

But my json doesn't have a root element, so what do I do?

Additionally, when using the suggested answer, the output is ("...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSURL *darkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/stats/DRK/BTC"];
NSData *darkData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:darkURL];
NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *darkDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:darkData options:0 error:&error];
NSString *lastP = [darkDict valueForKey:@"last_price"];
self.dark_label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@", lastP];
}
```

Comment: Convert the JSON to an `NSArray` with `NSJSONSerialization`. The access the value `NSString *value = array[0][@"last_price"];` If you are having trouble post the code you have written to get some help.

Comment: Sorry, was just about to post something and you posted at the same time. Was gonna say NSDictionary *darkDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:darkData options:0 error:&error];

    NSDecimalNumber *lastP = [darkDict valueForKey:@"last_price"];
    
    NSLog(@"%@", lastP);

Comment: @nimmbl : The response you're getting is not a dictionary but an array of a dictionary. Notice the first character? It's a square bracket indicating an array. Technically, your root element is index 0 and not a key.

Comment: @Chris `json doesn't have a root element`, not true because the json object you see is an element of this array

Answer (score 1):

Convert the JSON to an `NSArray` with `NSJSONSerialization`. Then access the value:

```
NSData *darkData = [@"[{\"code\":\"DRK\",\"exchange\": \"BTC\",\"last_price\": \"0.01790000\",\"yesterday_price\": \"0.01625007\",\"top_bid\": \"0.01790000\"}, {\"top_ask\": \"0.01833999\"}]" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:darkData 
                                                 options:0 
                                                   error:&error]; 
NSString *value = array[0][@"last_price"];

NSLog(@"value: %@", value);
```

NSLog output:

> value: 0.01790000

If you are having trouble post the code you have written to get some help.

-- updated for new OP code:

The web service returns a JSON **array or dictionaries** not a JSON **dictionary**. First you have to index into the array and then index into the dictionary.

```
NSURL *darkURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.mintpal.com/v1/market/stats/DRK/BTC"];
NSData *darkData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:darkURL];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *darkArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:darkData options:0 error:&error];

NSDictionary *darkDict = darkArray[0];
NSString *lastP = [darkDict valueForKey:@"last_price"];
NSLog(@"lastP: %@", lastP);
```

NSLog output:

> lastP: 0.01970000

Note that the two lines:

```
NSDictionary *darkDict = darkArray[0];
NSString *lastP = [darkDict valueForKey:@"last_price"];
```

can be replaced with the single line using array indexing:

```
NSString *lastP = darkArray[0][@"last_price"];
```

Where the "[0]" gets the first array element which is a `NSDictionary` and the "[@"last_price"]" gets the names item from the dictionary.

Comment: Awesome, thanks @zaph. If I use the above and apply the result to a UILabel.text, I get a clean output. If I use the NSDictionary with valueForKey:@"last..." I get ("0.179000"  Why is that?

Comment: Please supply an entire example, add that to your question. Something that can be copied and pasted into Xcode.

Comment: The web service returns a JSON **array** not a JSON **dictionary**. First you have to index into the array and then index into the dictionary. In your code if you log the class of the instance darkDict your get: `__NSArrayI`. Code: `NSLog(@"darkDict: %@", NSStringFromClass([darkDict class]));`

Comment: It's probably safer to use `firstObject` instead of grabbing index 0 especially as it's external data.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are wanting to iterate over your results. The root element is an array not a dictionary so you can just start iterating

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *items = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:darkData 
                                                    options:kNilOptions
                                                      error:&error];

if (!items) {
  NSLog(@"JSONSerialization error %@", error.localizedDescription); 
}

for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
  NSLog(@"last_price => %@", item[@"last_price"]);
}
```

If you literally just want to collect an array of the last_price's then you can so this

```
NSArray *lastPrices = [items valueForKey:@"last_price"];
```